# Mistyped method call with colon syntax. No error. But what does it mean?

Tags: raku

I made a typo calling a method with the colon syntax. I missed the space after the colon and the second colon for the named parameter. I've replicated my problem with a simple class:

```
class Test {
    method myMethod  {
        say "myMethod";
        say %_;
    } 
}

Test.new.myMethod:test<this>; #mistyped call
Test.new.myMethod: :test<this>; #actual call
#Test.new.myMethod:"some_string";
```

The output is:

```
myMethod
{}
myMethod
{test => this}
```

1. The first myMethod call with no error and no named arguments.
2. The second works as expected.
3. The third generates a colon pair compile
   time error

What does the syntax of the first call mean and why is it not an error? Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Identifiers of the form `foo:bar`, `foo:<baz>`, `foo:quux<waldo>`, `foo:quux<waldo>:abc<def>` etc. are [*extended* identifiers](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/identifiers#Extended_identifiers).

The symbol's longname is aliased to its shortname, the first component of the identifier, so in this case `myMethod:test<this>` is aliased to `myMethod`.

Comment: ahhh..I'll read up more on extended identifiers.  From the link you sent I have a follow up question:  I haven't defined an extended identifier for `myMethod:test<this>`  so why can I call it? Is it not a unique name?

Comment: @drclaw: when faced with a call `.myMethod:test<this>()`, Rakudo will always invoke the method `myMethod`, which looks like a bug to me; note that it is possible to invoke a method with a longname via quoted method names, ie `."myMethod:test<this>"()`